# App routing issues after deploying polymer starter-kit to a nginx subfolder

Tags: nginx, deployment, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I have some issues with the polymer app-routing after deploying the starter-kit to a nginx docker container.

First, the steps I have done to deploy the example:

1. I created the starter-kit project with *polymer init starter-kit*.
2. After that, I had to remove the first "/" from `<link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">` (href in index.html).
3. I built the test app and copy the unbundled version to the nginx docker container (folder /usr/share/nginx/test/unbundled)
4. I configured the nginx server as follows (nginx.conf):

   ```
   events {}
   http {
       server {
           charset UTF-8;
           listen 80;
           server_name localhost;
           root /usr/share/nginx/test;
           index index.html;

           location /unbundled {
           root /usr/share/nginx/test;
           }
       }}
   ```
5. After that I started the nginx server and opened the url `http://localhost/unbundled`

Now to my issue:
After Step 5 I thought that I land on the view1-page. But 404 page appears. 
After clicking on view1 the proper page was visible but then the url isn't correct anymore. Instead of getting `http://localhost/unbundled/view1` the click on this link resolve the url `http://localhost/view1`. I understand why (a href points to /view), but I don't not know how I can solve this issue. I don't know if its a polymer app-routing or a nginx-configuration problem.

Could someone give me a hint here how I can deploy apps with app-routing into a subfolder and get the app-routing navigation done correctly?

Best Regards 
Alex

Comment: Hi! I think that you need to specify `^/unbundled/` in `urlSpaceRegex` attribute of your [`app-location`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route?active=app-location#property-urlSpaceRegex) to let it work well under a subpath of your domain.

Comment: Does your index.html have a base tag defined as <base href="/unbundled/" >http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp? With that you shouldn't need to remove the / in the import